# How to prepare half dynamic web page with best performance?

Tags: performance, dynamic, static, backend

Imagine you have a web page which has some static contents and some dynamic contents based on the user's session. For example, you may see a webpage with a menu at top of the page which displays username but the remaining content is completely cachable and static.

There could be a simple solution to achieve that:

1. You can handle the dynamic part of the page in the client side with ajax request (which is not cachable) e.g. single page applications.
2. There may be another solution that client sends a request to a middleware(e.g. API Gateway) and the middleware fetches static part from cache and dynamic part from the backend then returns aggregated content to the client.
3. In my idea, the worst solution is to disable the cache.

What Facebook is doing, loads dynamic part at first request, and loads remaining contents with XHR requests.

**Questions:**

- What is the best practice for this issue?
- What would be the drawback of the second solution?
- What do you think about Stackoverflow top menu that displays your username?

Comment: too broad......

Answer (score 1):

An AJAX request (or fetch, or any other HTTP based request) may well be cached by using a RESTful service.

For more fine grained controll over what should be cached you could use a service worker, for example by adding https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/ to your application.

If your dynamic data has to be updated live, you should also have a look at WebSockets. Depending on your stack you could use a wrapper library like SignalR, socket.io or simply follow one of the tutorials at http://websocketd.com/